# Distribution based on Min Max

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and have following dataset (through a complex query)

| Item | Qty | Customer | Rank | Min | Max | Distribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1500 | 0101 | 1 | 250 | 600 | ???? |
| 001 | 1500 | 0104 | 2 | 0 | 500 | ???? |
| 001 | 1500 | 0103 | 3 | 100 | 300 | ???? |
| 001 | 1500 | 0105 | 4 | 200 | 300 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0104 | 1 | 200 | 600 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0105 | 2 | 150 | 700 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0101 | 3 | 100 | 200 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0103 | 4 | 100 | 500 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0102 | 5 | 50 | 200 | ???? |

There are multiple items (Item) and each item has fixed quantity available (Qty)

Each item is distributed in different customers (Customers) based on their rank (Rank). The ranks are group by for every item.

From the total quantity (Qty) of each item, every customer must get minimum quantity mentioned in (Min) column irrespective of its rank.

The remaining quantity of every item must be distribute based on the rank of the customer making sure that it should not exceed to the maximum quantity mentioned in (Max) column.

It is OK, if total quantity of the item is not consumed after distribution maximum quantity to all customer.

What I am after is the result something like this:

| Item | Qty | Customer | Rank | Min | Max | Distribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1500 | 0101 | 1 | 250 | 600 | 600 |
| 001 | 1500 | 0104 | 2 | 0 | 500 | 500 |
| 001 | 1500 | 0103 | 3 | 100 | 300 | 200 |
| 001 | 1500 | 0105 | 4 | 200 | 300 | 200 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0104 | 1 | 200 | 600 | 600 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0105 | 2 | 150 | 700 | 700 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0101 | 3 | 100 | 200 | 200 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0103 | 4 | 100 | 500 | 450 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0102 | 5 | 50 | 200 | 50 |

How can I achieve values in (Distribute) column. I am trying to generate this result through SQL Server Query.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In future please post consumable test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    Item char(3) NOT NULL
    ,Qty int NOT NULL
    ,Customer char(4) NOT NULL
    ,[Rank] int NOT NULL
    ,[Min] int NOT NULL
    ,[Max] int NOT NULL
    ,Distribute int NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (Item, [Rank])
);
INSERT INTO #t
VALUES ('001', 1500, '0101', 1, 250, 600, NULL)
    ,('001', 1500, '0104', 2, 0, 500, NULL)
    ,('001', 1500, '0103', 3, 100, 300, NULL)
    ,('001', 1500, '0105', 4, 200, 300, NULL)
    ,('002', 2000, '0104', 1, 200, 600, NULL)
    ,('002', 2000, '0105', 2, 150, 700, NULL)
    ,('002', 2000, '0101', 3, 100, 200, NULL)
    ,('002', 2000, '0103', 4, 100, 500, NULL)
    ,('002', 2000, '0102', 5, 50, 200, NULL)
    ,('003', 200, '0103', 1, 190, 500, NULL)
    ,('003', 200, '0102', 2, 50, 200, NULL)
    ,('003', 200, '0102', 3, 50, 200, NULL);
```

Try something like:

```
WITH MinQtysLeft
AS
(
    SELECT Item, Qty, Customer, [Rank], [Min], [Max], Distribute
        ,Qty - SUM([Min]) OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY [Rank]) As QtyLeft
    FROM #t
)
, MinQtys
AS
(
    SELECT Item, Qty, Customer, [Rank], [Min], [Max]
        ,CASE
            WHEN QtyLeft > 0
            THEN [Min]
            WHEN [Min] + QtyLeft > 0
            THEN [Min] + QtyLeft
            ELSE 0
        END AS Distribute
        ,MIN(CASE WHEN QtyLeft > 0 THEN QtyLeft ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Item) AS QtyAfterMin
    FROM MinQtysLeft
)
, MaxQtysLeft
AS
(
    SELECT Item, Qty, Customer, [Rank], [Min], [Max], Distribute
        ,QtyAfterMin - SUM([Max] - [Min]) OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY [Rank]) As QtyLeft
    FROM MinQtys
)
SELECT Item, Qty, Customer, [Rank], [Min], [Max]
    ,Distribute +
        CASE
            WHEN QtyLeft > 0
            THEN [Max] - [Min]
            WHEN [Max] - [Min] + QtyLeft > 0
            THEN [Max] - [Min] + QtyLeft
            ELSE 0
        END AS Distribute
FROM MaxQtysLeft;
```

Without windowed functions:

```
CREATE TABLE #work
(
    Item char(3) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL
    ,Qty int NOT NULL
    ,Customer char(4) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL
    ,[Rank] int NOT NULL
    ,[Min] int NOT NULL
    ,[Max] int NOT NULL
    ,Distribute int NULL
    ,QtyLeft int NULL
    ,QtyAfterMin int NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (Item, [Rank])
);

INSERT INTO #work (Item, Qty, Customer, [Rank], [Min], [Max])
SELECT Item, Qty, Customer, [Rank], [Min], [Max]
FROM #t;

UPDATE W1
SET QtyLeft = W1.Qty - X.SumMin
FROM #work W1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT SUM([Min]) AS SumMin
        FROM #work W2
        WHERE W2.Item = W1.Item
            AND W2.[Rank] <= W1.[Rank]
    ) X;

UPDATE #work
SET Distribute =
        CASE
            WHEN QtyLeft > 0
            THEN [Min]
            WHEN [Min] + QtyLeft > 0
            THEN [Min] + QtyLeft
            ELSE 0
        END;

WITH QtyAfterMins
AS
(
    SELECT Item
        ,MIN(CASE WHEN QtyLeft > 0 THEN QtyLeft ELSE 0 END) AS QtyAfterMin
    FROM #work
    GROUP BY Item
)
UPDATE W
SET QtyAfterMin = Q.QtyAfterMin
FROM #work W
    JOIN QtyAfterMins Q
        ON W.Item = Q.Item;

UPDATE W1
SET QtyLeft = W1.QtyAfterMin - X.SumMaxMin
FROM #work W1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT SUM([Max] - [Min]) AS SumMaxMin
        FROM #work W2
        WHERE W2.Item = W1.Item
            AND W2.[Rank] <= W1.[Rank]
    ) X;

UPDATE #work
SET Distribute = Distribute +
        CASE
            WHEN QtyLeft > 0
            THEN [Max] - [Min]
            WHEN [Max] - [Min] + QtyLeft > 0
            THEN [Max] - [Min] + QtyLeft
            ELSE 0
        END;

UPDATE T
SET Distribute = W.Distribute
FROM #t T
    JOIN #work W
        ON T.Item = W.Item
            AND T.[Rank] = W.[Rank];

select * from #t;
```

Comment: This code is given following error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: SQL2008 must not support ORDER BY with SUM. SQL 2008 went out of extended support 3 years ago so there will have been no security updates in that time. Even SQL 2012 went out of extended support 2 days ago. You will have to try some sort of triangular join instead.

Comment: If I bring this data in Excel... can I calculate "Distribute" column in Excel?

Comment: You can do all sorts of things. You should really upgrade to at least SQL2014 and ideally SQL2019. If you really have to use SQL2008 I suspect the simplest approach would be to use a working temp table and run multiple updates against it to avoid windowed functions. It is not very efficient but I will add it to the above.

Comment: The solution is working, but it is not group by items. it is applying to overall records. The quantity distribution should be based on each item.

Comment: It conforms to the expected result you gave for your test data.

Answer (score 0):

With a recursive common table expression,RCTE, compute the running amounts of container*minQty and container*(maxQty-minQty) per item,order by rank. Those amounts are used for the distribution count of each item:if sum(container*minQty)>=itemQty then each item will get no more than container*minQty (distribute itemQty by using running amount of container*minQty), if sum(container*minQty)<itemQty then each item will get at least container*minQty plus any of the remaining items (distribute itemQty-sum(container*minQty) by using  running amounts of container*(maxQty-minQty)).

```sql
CREATE TABLE #planningData
(
    itemCode char(5) NOT NULL
    , buyerCode char(5) NOT NULL
    , [rank] int NOT NULL
    , [containerCount] int NOT NULL
    , [itemQty] int NOT NULL
    , [minQty] int NOT NULL
    , [maxQty] int NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #planningData
VALUES ('02-474', '18', 1, 6, 31, 6, 12)
, ('01-145', '35', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
, ('01-005', '28', 1, 4, 287, 2, 7)
, ('01-005', '09', 2, 4, 287, 2, 5)
, ('01-005', '30', 3, 2, 287, 0, 0)
, ('01-005', '37', 4, 3, 287, 10, 60)
, ('01-005', '03', 5, 4, 287, 10, 60)
, ('01-735', '28', 1, 4, 222, 10, 15)
, ('01-735', '15', 2, 3, 222, 5, 18)
, ('01-735', '30', 3, 2, 222, 9, 27)
, ('01-735', '23', 4, 2, 222, 9, 27)
, ('01-735', '10', 5, 0, 222, 0, 0)
, ('01-735', '11', 6, 0, 222, 0, 0)
, ('01-735', '09', 7, 4, 222, 9, 18)
, ('01-735', '01', 8, 0, 222, 0, 0)
, ('01-735', '25', 9, 1, 222, 0, 0)
, ('01-735', '04', 10, 4, 222, 5, 15)
, ('01-735', '08', 11, 0, 222, 0, 0)
, ('01-089', '20', 1, 2, 63, 18, 100)
, ('01-089', '26', 2, 0, 63, 0, 0)
, ('01-089', '12', 3, 3, 63, 10, 40)
, ('01-010', '27', 1, 3, 336, 9, 18)
, ('01-010', '28', 2, 4, 336, 9, 27)
, ('01-010', '15', 3, 3, 336, 18, 36)
, ('01-010', '25', 4, 1, 336, 10, 30)
, ('01-010', '17', 5, 1, 336, 9, 27)
, ('01-010', '30', 6, 2, 336, 18, 36)
, ('01-010', '04', 7, 4, 336, 0, 0)
, ('01-010', '23', 8, 2, 336, 18, 36)
, ('01-010', '03', 9, 4, 336, 0, 0)
, ('01-010', '38', 10, 1, 336, 10, 30)
, ('01-010', '10', 11, 0, 336, 0, 0)
, ('01-010', '09', 12, 4, 336, 0, 0)
, ('01-010', '05', 13, 3, 336, 10, 30)
, ('01-010', '11', 14, 0, 336, 0, 0)
, ('01-010', '37', 15, 3, 336, 0, 0)
, ('01-899', '21', 1, 2, 49, 10, 20)
, ('01-899', '18', 2, 6, 49, 10, 30)
, ('01-011', '30', 1, 2, 15, 30, 40)
, ('01-796', '19', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
, ('01-009', '19', 1, 0, 271, 0, 0)
, ('01-009', '27', 2, 3, 271, 9, 18)
, ('01-009', '28', 3, 4, 271, 9, 18)
, ('01-009', '30', 4, 2, 271, 0, 0)
, ('01-009', '04', 5, 4, 271, 9, 18)
, ('01-009', '08', 6, 0, 271, 0, 0)
, ('01-009', '01', 7, 0, 271, 10, 15)
, ('01-009', '37', 8, 3, 271, 0, 0)
, ('01-009', '09', 9, 4, 271, 0, 0)
, ('01-009', '03', 10, 4, 271, 9, 27)
, ('01-088', '28', 1, 4, 0, 0, 0)
, ('01-088', '04', 2, 4, 0, 0, 0)
, ('01-088', '09', 3, 4, 0, 0, 0)
, ('01-088', '01', 4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
, ('01-088', '11', 5, 0, 0, 0, 0)
, ('01-088', '08', 6, 0, 0, 5, 10)
, ('01-744', '02', 1, 2, 1001, 5, 15)
, ('01-744', '10', 2, 1, 1001, 8, 10)
, ('02-038', '18', 1, 6, 14, 5, 15)
, ('01-736', '28', 1, 4, 65, 10, 22)
, ('01-092', '27', 1, 3, 88, 5, 15)
, ('01-092', '02', 2, 3, 88, 9, 36)
, ('01-092', '11', 3, 0, 88, 0, 0)
, ('01-092', '01', 4, 0, 88, 0, 0)
, ('01-092', '10', 5, 0, 88, 0, 0)
, ('01-092', '06', 6, 0, 88, 10, 15)
, ('01-092', '05', 7, 3, 88, 0, 0)
, ('01-093', '27', 1, 3, 185, 5, 15)
, ('01-093', '04', 2, 4, 185, 9, 27)
, ('01-093', '28', 3, 4, 185, 0, 0)
, ('01-093', '22', 4, 2, 185, 0, 0)
, ('01-093', '01', 5, 0, 185, 0, 0)
, ('01-093', '02', 6, 3, 185, 0, 0)
, ('01-093', '05', 7, 3, 185, 0, 0)
, ('01-094', '29', 1, 3, 6, 9, 100)
, ('01-094', '28', 2, 4, 6, 2, 50)
, ('01-095', '30', 1, 2, 27, 9, 45)
, ('01-095', '23', 2, 2, 27, 9, 45)
, ('01-095', '08', 3, 0, 27, 0, 0)
, ('01-095', '01', 4, 0, 27, 0, 0)
, ('01-095', '02', 5, 3, 27, 4, 10)
, ('01-095', '06', 6, 0, 27, 0, 0)
, ('02-480', '38', 1, 1, 30, 9, 18)
, ('02-480', '05', 2, 3, 30, 9, 18)
, ('01-745', '28', 1, 4, 31, 5, 15)
, ('01-097', '28', 1, 4, 218, 9, 18)
, ('01-097', '37', 2, 3, 218, 9, 18)
, ('01-097', '08', 3, 0, 218, 5, 10)
, ('01-097', '03', 4, 4, 218, 9, 18)
, ('01-097', '11', 5, 0, 218, 0, 0)
, ('01-097', '09', 6, 4, 218, 5, 15)
, ('01-097', '38', 7, 1, 218, 5, 9)
, ('01-097', '04', 8, 4, 218, 0, 0)
, ('01-097', '05', 9, 3, 218, 5, 9)
, ('01-097', '06', 10, 0, 218, 10, 15)
, ('01-097', '02', 11, 3, 218, 9, 18)
, ('01-097', '01', 12, 0, 218, 27, 54)
, ('01-098', '28', 1, 4, 1016, 27, 50)
, ('01-098', '27', 2, 3, 1016, 27, 50)
, ('01-098', '09', 3, 4, 1016, 36, 72)
, ('01-098', '06', 4, 0, 1016, 10, 15)
, ('01-098', '05', 5, 3, 1016, 36, 72)
, ('01-098', '10', 6, 0, 1016, 0, 0)
, ('01-098', '04', 7, 4, 1016, 27, 63)
, ('01-098', '11', 8, 0, 1016, 0, 0)
, ('01-098', '37', 9, 3, 1016, 18, 63)
, ('01-098', '38', 10, 1, 1016, 36, 72)
, ('01-098', '01', 11, 0, 1016, 27, 36)
, ('01-098', '02', 12, 3, 1016, 27, 63)
, ('01-098', '08', 13, 0, 1016, 5, 10)
, ('01-098', '02', 14, 4, 1016, 18, 36);

WITH RCTE AS (
SELECT itemCode,buyerCode,rank,containerCount,itemQty,minQty,maxQty, 
(SELECT SUM(I.containerCount*I.minQty) FROM #planningData AS I WHERE I.itemCode=PD.itemCode) AS summinQty,
containerCount*minQty AS runTotMin,containerCount*(maxQty-minQty) AS runTotMaxDiffMin
FROM #planningData AS PD
WHERE PD.rank = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT PD.itemCode,PD.buyerCode,PD.rank,PD.containerCount,PD.itemQty,PD.minQty,PD.maxQty,R.summinQty,
R.runTotMin+(PD.containerCount*PD.minQty),R.runTotMaxDiffMin+(PD.containerCount*(PD.maxQty-PD.minQty))
FROM RCTE AS R
JOIN #planningData AS PD ON R.itemCode=PD.itemCode AND R.rank+1=PD.rank)
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN summinQty>=itemQty THEN 
  CASE
  WHEN runTotMin<=itemQty THEN containerCount*minQty 
  WHEN runTotMin>itemQty AND runTotMin-(containerCount*minQty)<itemQty THEN itemQty-(runTotMin-(containerCount*minQty))
  ELSE 0 
  END
ELSE
  CASE 
  WHEN summinQty+runTotMaxDiffMin<=itemQty THEN containerCount*maxQty 
  WHEN summinQty+runTotMaxDiffMin>itemQty AND summinQty+runTotMaxDiffMin-(containerCount*(maxQty-minQty))<itemQty THEN
       (containerCount*minQty)+itemQty-(summinQty+runTotMaxDiffMin-(containerCount*(maxQty-minQty)))
  ELSE containerCount*minQty
  END
END AS distCount
FROM RCTE
ORDER BY itemCode,rank;
```

Comment: Can you please explain R.rank+1=PD.rank as because of this, the Union is not showing all records. Secondly, the query above not calculating correctly in case where there are 3 or more records with 0 min and 0 max in middle of the same item and then there is record with more than 0 min max value... The distCount value comes to 0 in that case.. which is not correct.

Comment: The way SQL Server calculate the rank is that if an item score is same for two or more buyer... it gives the same rank... for example... it gives rank 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7....... where 3, 3, 3 buyer has the same rank because all of them has the same score..... because of this.. what your query is doing is not picking up those records because of join condition R.rank+1=PD.rank.... is there a way to resolve it or is there a way for SQL server to calculate rank as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 instead of 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7... I am calculate rank by RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY itemCode ORDER BY score DESC)

Comment: resolved through row_number function instead of rank